# Index Match- display only recent result

Tags: excel, indexing, match

Example of excel sheet:

[image]

I am creating a spread sheet for work. In column D my formula is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('2015 Daily Log'!$A$5:$A$980,MATCH(PMI!A2,IF("pmi"='2015 Daily Log'!$J$5:$J$980,'2015 Daily Log'!$C$5:$C$980,0),0))," ")
```

In sheet one is the Daily log, so in this second sheet the goal is to have a list of every vehicle (Column A), the last time the vehicle as inspected as per the log (Column D), and when the next inspection would occur (Column E).

Since we keep other information in the log I Have filtered to only display the trucks that came in for "pmi" as oppose to having the brakes change, etc. The only problem I'm having is that if the vehicle in A4 comes in for service 02/12/16, the worksheet doesn't update because it only looks at the first log.

I was trying to find a way to use the large function or the dmax, but I just don't seem to know how to get the function to work. My goal is to have the formula return the most recent date.

Comment: Can you also show your Daily log?

Comment: Did the answer provided work for you?  If it did please mark as correct.  It is something only you can do.  It will close out the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try MAX(IF())

```
=IFERROR(MAX(IF(A2='2015 Daily Log'!$C$5:$C$980,IF("pmi"='2015 Daily Log'!$J$5:$J$980,'2015 Daily Log'!$A$5:$A$980))),"")
```

This is an array formula.  Confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Then copy down.